# Refer to values in ConfigMap and Secret resources in ArgoCD Application

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd, kustomize

I want to deploy a remote helm chart to my cluster and within the helm values, I need to specify specific tokens that I have already created as secrets ( managed by the external secret operator).

How can I reference the values from the Secrets or ConfigMap in the `helm` or `kustomize` section of the ArgoCD Application?

For reference, with FluxCD, I can use [valuesFrom](https://fluxcd.io/flux/guides/helmreleases/#refer-to-values-in-configmap-and-secret-resources) to reference a value in ConfigMap or Secret. How can I achieve the same with the Application?

Comment: what is the remote helm chart?

Comment: Show us some concrete example. Does the Helm chart support referencing an existing Secret?

Comment: I have never used FluxCD, but this `valuesFrom` to reference values in ConfigMap or secrets is a must have IMHO. Have you found any solutino to achieve this in Argo CD?

Answer (score -1):

With Kustomize, take a look at [SecretGenerator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_secretgenerator_) and [ConfigMapGenerator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_configmapgenerator_).

In HELM you have such options:

1. Create Secret/Config maps from files by using [glob patterns](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions).
2. By using values.yaml, for example ([flow control](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)):

values.yaml

```
secretMap:
  secret: "too_secret_info"
```

SecretMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-example
data:
  {{- with .Values.secretMap}}
  secret-file: {{ .secret }}
  {{- end }}
```